# ASP.net, how to make my dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist on my ASP.net page. It contains the primary key values from another table. It is using these values to put into a new, intersection table.

My problem is that, for readability/usability, displaying the primary keys themselves is not ideal. I would prefer to display the corresponding name field, but insert the primary key all the same. I have tried changing the datatextfield and leaving the value field as the pk and selecting either or both columns, but when I try to input it comes back as saying that a null value cannot be accepted.

Can anyone help please?

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataTextField="BoatID" DataValueField="BoatID">
     </asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Rowing ClubConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BoatID] FROM [Boat]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Thank you!

The following is the error page that comes up when trying to add to the table when the datatextfield has been changed to boat name and the sql includes the boat name column:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BoatID', table 'Rowing Club.dbo.SessionBoats'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BoatID', table 'Rowing Club.dbo.SessionBoats'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BoatID', table 'Rowing Club.dbo.SessionBoats'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1767866
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5352418
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +269
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1406
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +205
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +380
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +399
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +81
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleInsert(String commandArg, Boolean causesValidation) +365
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +584
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +89
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +121
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +156
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9528682
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Comment: Change the DataTextField, and add the name field to your SQL query. That is the correct way. I know you said it didn't work, but we know for sure that will be at least part of the solution. Once you've done that, tell us what the exact exception is and which line it occurs at. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: Does the above addition give any indication of the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's something related to the data you're trying to insert into your database. You should check for blank (null) data.